# Relational database design:two 1 to many relations

Tags: database-design, relational-database

I have i table users (id,name) and operations (id,date,id_user,id_target_user)

if i didn't have the id_target_user column I'll just make on relation 
from the users.id to operations.id_user (every user can have multiple several operations)
but the problem is the operation maybe related to another user

how to solve this?
i can't create 2 relations on the same key can i?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can.

- `id_user` is a foreign key to `users.id`.
- `id_target_user` is a foreign key to
  `users.id`.

That's all you need.

Comment: Thanks but i tried to do so in Microsoft Access and in MySQL but it didn't work

Comment: There is no reason that is not possible, please explain what you did (like put your sql create query in your question).